# How to select a sheet with a formula while sheet name change dynamically with INDIRECT

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to set an **ARRAYFORMULA** or something similar in **C3** which can read a sheet while name is changing dynamically with **INDIRECT** , so I can get the postions of each values with **XMATCH** :

[image: Here the issue]

[What's inside a sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmM1Y.png)

I first tried to do this in **D3**:

> XMATCH(A3:A;INDIRECT(B3:B&"!$1:$1"))

But 2 problems with this :
1: Length of Column **A** and **B** can change dynamically, so **C** has to be dynamic.
2: Not clean

In **C3** I set the following formula :

> ARRAYFORMULA(XMATCH(A3:A;INDIRECT(B3:B&"!$1:$1")))

and also tried :

> ARRAYFORMULA(XMATCH(A3:A;query(INDIRECT(B3:B&"!$1:$1");"select *")))

You can see this works only for the first sheet name "WHISKEY.US" and it seems pretty logical.

My bet is we have to use a **MAP** , but number of sheets may change so we cannot initialize things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give a shot at:

```
=map(A3:A;B3:B;lambda(a;b;if(len(a)*len(b);xmatch(a;indirect(b&"!1:1"));)))
```

Comment: It works! I really need to get familiar with those LAMBDA / MAP,REDUCE ect. functions. It seems to solve every problem, but looks pretty tough though.